# AngularJS - 'Controller not a function: Seperate controller files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module

I am getting the 'Controller is not a function error in my application.

From what I have read the most common issue is that it the controller file is not referenced in the `html` page - this is not the case for me.

I do not get the error when I have included the controller in the same file as declaring the module, but when I am using seperate files for each controller.

Here is my folder structure:

**app.js:**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'assets/views/mainView.html',
        controller: 'assets/controllers/mainController.js'
    });
});
```

**mainController.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name = "test";
}]);
```

I have also read that when you declare a module, the array braces [] create a new module so I took them out of the module in mainController.js.

It works if I do this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'assets/views/mainView.html',
        controller: 'mainController.js'
    });
});


myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.name = "hi";
}]);
```

I have referenced the controller like this in my index.html in the head section:

```
<script src="assets/scripts/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="assets/controllers/mainController.js"></script>
```

Comment: Remove var myApp = angular.module('myApp'); from controller file.

Comment: still the same result

Comment: you have given your controller's file path in config function like this : controller: 'assets/controllers/mainController.js' whereas as far i know it is the controller name and not path something like this in your case : controller: 'mainController'. Try doing this and let me know

Comment: thanks I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are having controller in another file no need to give path of the controller there which you have given in your config

```
    myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'assets/views/mainView.html',
     //Remove this
    //controller: 'assets/controllers/mainController.js'
     //and then try this
       controller: 'mainController'
   });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I would have never guessed that you dont need to specify the path to the controller...

Answer (score 1):

Are you using IIFE? If not you should not assign angular module 
`var myApp = angular.module('myApp');` on your `mainController.js` as it overwrite your `myApp` variable since it is treated as globe variable.

If you want to apply IIFE your code should be:

**app.js**

```
    (function () {
         var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

        myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'assets/views/mainView.html',
                controller: 'mainController'
            });
        });
    })();
```

**mainController.js**

```
    (function () {
        var myApp = angular.module('myApp');

        myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope){
            $scope.name = "test";
        }]);

    })();
```